# Two Wii u's. Two Minecraft discs. Two tvs. same house

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

I bought my two sons each a Wii U and Minecraft. How can they get in each other's worlds when playing from the same house but on different Wii U's and different TVs?

Comment: The Minecraft Wii U Edition should have a system link feature like all the other versions of the game

Answer (score 18):

Your sons must be friends with one another on their Wii U's through the [Miiverse](https://miiverse.nintendo.net/). According to this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wiiu/comments/43lwyt/minecraft_wii_u_online_multiplayer_not_local/):

> You have to add friends to play with them. You can add them in your friends list or through Miiverse!

You should be able to configure all of this on the Wii U itself, but if not, you can use the Miiverse link above.

Once they are friends with one another, they should be able to invite each other to one of their games and play together.  From what I'm reading, they will need to be using an HD TV each, as well as supported Wii Controllers (Wii U gamepad, Wii U Pro controller, or Wii Classic controller).

According to this [article](http://purenintendo.com/review-minecraft-wii-u-edition/) the multiplayer is free (I wasn't sure since I don't have the console).  As pointed out in comments, this is for all online multiplayer across all games on the Wii U.

Comment: to clarify the "multiplayer is free" comment: the Wii U doesn't require you to pay a monthly fee to play online multiplayer, as opposed to the Xbox One and PS4, which require you to pay a monthly subscription fee in order to have online multiplayer in Minecraft, on top of whatever you pay for your internet. The multiplayer itself is free.

Comment: @Nzall I figured that whats the article meant, but I didn't think it was necessary to state that so I left it out.

Comment: Just a fun fact in all of this - The Nintendo Switch will not have free multiplayer. [link](https://www.engadget.com/2017/01/12/nintendo-switch-multiplayer-wont-be-free/)